# Spring MVC Neither BindingResult nor plain target

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
So i got this error when i'm trying to run this web page, and i don't  know why.
I saw and read a lot about this error but i can't find out what is the problem.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web- app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

 <display-name>onallo_labor</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet_1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet_1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet_1-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

      <listener>
       <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
       </listener-class>
  </listener> 

</web-app>
```

servlet_1-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.petclinic.web"/>

</beans>
```

CreateController:

package onallo_labor;

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class CreateController {
    @RequestMapping(value="create",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView create(){
        return new ModelAndView("create","user",new User());
}
@RequestMapping(value="",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView welcome(){
    return new ModelAndView("welcome");
}
@RequestMapping(value="create_ready",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addContact(@ModelAttribute("user")
        User user,Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("username",user.getUsername());
    model.addAttribute("birthday",user.getBirthday());

    return "create_ready";
}
}
```

create.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>User Account Creation</title>
</head>
<body>

<div align="center">
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><h2>Registration Form</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Username: </td>
            <td><form:input path="username" id="djb"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password: </td>
            <td><form:password path="password"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Birthday: </td>
            <td><form:input path="birthday"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

The create_ready.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Submitted User Information</h2>
   <table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>${username}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Birthday</td>
    <td>${birthday}</td>
</tr>
</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

The User Class:

```
package onallo_labor;

public class User {
public User(){}
public String   username;
public String   password;
public String   birthday;
public String getUsername(){return this.username;}
public void setUsername(String un){this.username=un;}
public String getPassword(){return this.password;}
public void setPassword(String pw){this.password=pw;}
public String getBirthday(){return this.birthday;}
public void setBirthday(String bd){this.birthday=bd;}
}
```

There is a pic about the structure of the files.

http://kepkezelo.com/images/lm418k9xegg2aukio3.png

UPDATE1:
So i changed the method name's in the User class, now here is the error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /create.jsp at line 20

17:             </tr>
18:             <tr>
19:                 <td>Username: </td>
20:                 <td><form:input path="username" id="djb"/></td>
21:             </tr>
22:             <tr>
23:                 <td>Password: </td>


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:413)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:117)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
org.apache.jsp.create_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(create_jsp.java:181)
org.apache.jsp.create_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(create_jsp.java:125)
org.apache.jsp.create_jsp._jspService(create_jsp.java:78)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Instead of using modelAttribute try using commandName in your jsp

Comment: i tried it but then i got this error : An exception occurred processing JSP page
and thie again : Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

Comment: To clarify, you get the exception when you try to do a GET on `/create`?

Comment: yes, when i try to load the create page

Comment: Please post your User class

Comment: Are you sure you are showing us the correct controller method, as it currently is?

Comment: i rewrited the methods getUsername and getBirthday, but everything is the same as in my Eclipse

Comment: Those are not important right now. Are you showing us the correct `create()` method?

Comment: yes this is the correct method

Answer (score 0):

Your User class is wrong for it to be a java bean it has to follow certain naming conventions. Your setter and getter have wrong names, example,

```
'N' needs to be small
public String getUserName(){return this.username;}
Change to:
public String getUsername(){return this.username;}
```

Comment: `modelAttribute` and `commandName` are equivalent and use the same property in the underlying `FormTag`.

Comment: May be but what about the naming convention. is that wrong too?

Comment: ok i did what you told, i changed all the names in the User class, and tried whit modelattribute and with commandname now i got this:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /create.jsp at line 20

17:    </tr>
18:    <tr>
19:     <td>Username: </td>
20:     <td><form:input path="username" id="djb"/></td>
21:    </tr>
22:    <tr>
23:     <td>Password: </td>

Comment: I looked up the modelAttribute and commandName and you are right. But without the proper naming convention Spring wouldn't be able to bind the object attributes to the data

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a combination of things. You have

```
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value="create",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView create(){
    return new ModelAndView("create","user",new User());
}
```

The `ModelAndView` from the **portlet** library is not a [default recognized return type for the `DispatcherServlet` stack.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types) As such, it will be considered as a plain `Object` and added to the model itself. Because your URI is `.../create`, Spring will use that last path element to map to a view. So it will end up resolving your `create.jsp` as a view **but for the wrong reasons.**

Change your `ModelAndView` to

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
```

<sub>I don't know why you have a portlet dependency, but get rid of it if you don't need it.</sub>

You're also missing

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

from your servlet context.

You're `<servlet>` is mapped to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet_1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

so it's unclear to me what URL you're sending your request to, `../create.html`?

Comment: i changed it but nothing, still the "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute" error or the "An exception occurred processing JSP page /create.jsp"

Comment: @user3376275 Add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to your servlet context. You'll need to add the corresponding `mvc` namespace declarations as well.

Comment: @user3376275 What URL are you even using to access your application? Where is the `create.jsp` located in your web project?

Comment: http://kepkezelo.com/images/lm418k9xegg2aukio3.png
This  URL: http://localhost/onallo_labor/ loads the welcome.jsp and it works, and there is a link to create.jsp
<a href="create.jsp">Create User Account</a>
and its URL is:http://localhost/onallo_labor/create.jsp

Comment: @user Right. Your `DispatcherServlet` is completely not involved in forwarding to your JSP. There's a lot of things missing from your configuration. First, the element I spoke of before. Then you should add your own `InternalResourceViewResolver`. You should then move your  JSPs to some folder under `/WEB-INF` where they won't be visible from the outside.

Comment: @user3376275 Then change your `<url-pattern`> to something like `/*` that will handle all requests. Your current pattern is completely random for what you are trying to achieve.