# Difference between org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView class and org/springframework/web/portlet/ModelAndView

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-web

I have just answered the below question which revolves around this posted question.

[spring mvc InternalResourceViewResolver doesnt get prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298002/spring-mvc-internalresourceviewresolver-doesnt-get-prefix/31299345#31299345)

Can someone out there tell the difference between the classes

`org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView` and `org/springframework/web/portlet/ModelAndView`

I see almost similar API docs for both

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html

and

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/ModelAndView.html

where both have the constructor

```
ModelAndView(String viewName)
Convenient constructor when there is no model data to expose.
```

and yet the latter doesn't work in resolving the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring that these two are meant for two completely different environments, the difference is that `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView` is a [supported handler method return type](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types):

> - A `ModelAndView` object, with the model implicitly enriched with command objects and the results of `@ModelAttribute` annotated reference data accessor methods.

That means that Spring has a [`HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.html) implementation ([`ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler.html)) that will receive the return value of type `ModelAndView` and process it.

It does not have such a implementation for `org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView` registered by default.

More:

- [Spring MVC Neither BindingResult nor plain target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156112/spring-mvc-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target)
- [How does `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828834/spring-3-2-responsebody-not-working-with-a-model-return-value)